# Grails GSP null safety check trouble

Tags: grails

I am trying to populate a text field on my GSP as such:

```
<label>Phone(aaa-bbb-cccc):</label>&nbsp<g:textField name="phone" style ="border-radius: 5px" 
                    value="${recordToEdit.telephones = [] ? null : recordToEdit.telephones.first()}"></g:textField><br>
```

but it still tell me I can't access first() on an empty list. telephones is a List of Strings each being a phone number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as @gross-jonas pointed out, the `recordToEdit.telephones = [] ? .. : ..`  is terribly wrong already, unless it's a typo

the check you are trying to make should look like:

```
value="${recordToEdit.telephones ? recordToEdit.telephones.first() : ''}"
```

or

```
value="${recordToEdit.telephones?.getAt( 0 ) ?: ''}"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just use the Null Safe Operator (?.) as

```
${recordToEdit.telephones?.first()}
```

for null checks, which is not sufficient.

UPDATE

for empty list checks and null checks,

```
${ recordToEdit.telephones ? recordToEdit.telephones[0] : '' }
```

will be good.

Comment: `[].first()` throws `NoSuchElementException`, so null safe check wont help much

Comment: @injecteer Got carried away (it was the coffee I hadn't had this morning). Correct you are. Updated accordingly.

Comment: there's a gotcha with subscript operator :)

Answer (score 1):

Dude, didn't you just mean `==` instead of `=` ?

It looks like you are overwriting your `telephones` which get issued successfully instead of comparing it.

Comment: the opposite notation would definitely help >)